# How to manage hardware cache usage

Tags: c, caching, memory, hardware

I wonder if there is a way to directly manage which parts of the memory are loaded into (*and kept in*) the cache. I know that there is __builtin_prefetch() in gcc, but I would need a bit more (at least I think I would...).

Here is my problem:
I have a loop where I update a vector v (*very* pseudocode):

```
while (1) {
    update_an_entry_in_v;
}
```

The length of v is in the millions. The loop runs 100s of millions times, and it jumps around in v. Therefore my cache-hit ratio is really bad, and there is no way of getting all of v into L1 cache.

I can reorganize the code like this:

```
for (i=0; i < length_of_v; i+=1024) {
    while (1) {
        update_an_entry_in_v[i:i+1023];
    }
}
```

That is, first only work with those updates that I know will update only entries in v[0:1023], process all of those, then go to the next block, etc.

Now this is probably going to have a much better cache behaviour, but I wonder if it is possible to make it even better. Let's focus on the v[0:1023] block. I still will jump around within v[0:1023], so the hardware may think that there is no need to keep parts of that chunk of memory in L1 cache any longer, and then, boom!, I go back to that chunk again.

So the question becomes: is there a way to mark the whole v[0:1023] so that it gets loaded into L1 before the inner while loop, and then "unmark" it once the while loop is finished?

(Obviously, 1024 is just a convenient number that should be tuned. With doubles that's 8K memory, and given that these days most machines have at least 32-64K L1 data cache that should leave enough for everything else.)

Comment: On which processor (CPU) and compiler?

Comment: Any and all :-). But primarily Intel cpus with gcc on linux, and icc on both windows and linux. Power systems would also be interesting.

Comment: Have you benchmarked this? Generally, the issue you describe shouldn't be that much of a problem.

Comment: Well, I can benchmark the blockupdate code, but see if there is anything further to gain I'd need to know first how to handle the cache...

Answer (score 1):

Obviously I don't know what you're doing, and this somewhat sidesteps the issue, but if you know the indicies could you radix sort the indicies and then just run through the entire thing in order which would be cache efficient? Perhaps order they're updated matters but from the comment about reorganizing the code I guessed, on the off chance it didn't, I'd mention it. [Well, order is somewhat preserved doing this since radix sort is stable, but only when it's the same index].

Comment: When I do the updates then I stream through other arrays that are in order. So if I change the order to benefit v, then I'm facing the same cache issues on the other arrays :-(.

Comment: BTW, your question is very valid. After all, if I can update in blocks then why can't I specify the block size to be 1? The reason is that the bigger the blocks I update in one chunk the longer the other other arrays are that I need to stream through. At the two extreme I face really bad cache-performance: if the block contains everything then v's cache is bad; if I get down to 1-sized blocks then the other arrays'. I'm trying to find a happy medium for the block size, and whatever part of v fits into L1 seems to be the best. Keeping that block all in L1 ...

Comment: ... could provide a bit more bonus if I knew how to do it.

Comment: I mean, this could be a silly idea, but could you break the process into two steps allowing you to do one part of the process in a cache efficient order, reorder data from the intermediary step to be in the correct order for the second half, and then complete the operations in the correct order for the second array? Obviously this would use a ton more space (maybe even twice the memory you're using now), but if the re-order is cache efficient it could still be faster. [I'm not sure if this is off topic or not, you probably already went through these ideas, sorry if so].